# Spring retry template is not working with @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-retry

In the case of database unavailability, I need to retry executing my service method 3 times. For this, I use Spring Retry Template. But with @Transactional annotation, when DB is unavailable a specific exception can't be caught.

```
@Configuration
public class RetryTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public  RetryTemplate createRetryTemplate(){
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

        FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(5000l);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);

        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        return retryTemplate;
    }

}


@Service
public class MessageService {

    @Autowired
    private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

    @Autowired
    MessageRepo messageRepo;

    @Transactional
    public void sendMessage(Message message) throws RuntimeException{

        retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
            log.info("Executing for {}  " ,  retryContext.getRetryCount());
            Message model = new Message();
            messageRepo.save(model);
            return "";
        });
    }
}
```

But if I try using @Retryable when the database is unavailable the retry happens successfully for RuntimeExcption and calls the @Recover method at the end of the retry.

```
@Service
@EnableRetry
public class MessageService {

    @Autowired
    private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

    @Autowired
    MessageRepo messageRepo;

    @Retryable(
            value = {RuntimeException.class},
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000),
            maxAttempts = 5
    )
    @Transactional
    public void sendMessage(Message message) throws RuntimeException{
        Message model = new Message();
        messageRepo.save(model);
    }
}


    @Recover
    public void recover(){
        log.info("Recover is called ");
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain the reason for these two different behaviours and suggest me the best way of retrying? (I'm using JPA data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, while using the retryTemplate, the exception occurs even before the execution reaches the `retryTemplate.execute(...)` call because spring is not able to open the transaction you need ( *through the `@Transactional` annotation, since opening a transaction needs a DB connection* ),

So the exception happens on spring framework level, not in your method, Therefore your retry template is useless in this case.

In the second case, opening the transaction happens inside a retry scope, so the retry catches the exception and all is good.